# IOS 6 UIView animation completion

Tags: ios6, uiviewanimation

Any idea why the following code does not working under IOS 6, while it runs perfectly under IOS 5 executing the NSLog  but on IOS 6 (both in simulator and iPad) the NSLog does not executed at all!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0f animations:^{ [self.view setAlpha:0.7f];}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ if(finished)  NSLog(@"Finished !!!!!!");}];
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Is nothing happening or the wrong thing? Where are you calling it?

Comment: Ir runs perfectly under IOS 5 responding "finished" but on IOS 6 (both in simulator and iPad) the NSLog does not executing at all!

Comment: I seem to have run into a very similar issue today. I have an animation block that works fine on iOS 5, but on iOS 6 the completion block never fires.

Answer (score 8):

Here the Code

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                    [self.view setAlpha:0.7f];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if(finished)  NSLog(@"Finished !!!!!");
                     // do any stuff here if you want
                 }];
```

Comment: Needs to be UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut, not UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut